# How do I find keys in my hash to map to elements that match a condition?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash that maps integers to arrays.  For example

```
{1 => ["abc"], 2 => ["ccc", "ddd"]}
```

How do I get all the keys from my hash that have arrays with at least 2 elements in them?

Comment: You can use `select` or `reject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{1 => ["abc"], 2 => ["ccc", "ddd"]}.select{|_, a| a.length > 1}.keys
# => [2]
```

Comment: This answer seems more flexible  
result = hash.select{|_, a| a.length > 1} #hash with the value/pair that meet the requirement  
  result.keys                               #the keys

Answer (score 2):

Anything like this?

```
hash.each_key.select { |key| hash[key].count >= 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

One more possible solution :)

```
{1 => ["abc"], 2 => ["ccc", "ddd"]}.map { |k, v| k if v.size > 1 }.compact
# => [2]
```