# How do I iterate through a hash until I find a matching element?

Tags: ruby, hash, detect

I have a hash that maps integers to arrays.  For example

```
{1 => ["abc"], 2 => ["ccc", "ddd"]}
```

How do I iterate through the hash until I find an entry in which the value only has an array size of 1?  Normally I could do

```
arr.detect{|element| element.size == 1}
```

but that only works for arrays.  I'm not sure how to apply a similar logic to hashes.

Comment: Take a look at the [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46656045/477037) – hashes take **two arguments** in these methods, the key and its value, i.e. `detect { |k, v| ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same principle applies:

```
h = {1 => ["abc"], 2 => ["ccc", "ddd"]}

h.find do |_, l|
  l.size == 1
end
# => [ 1, ["abc"]]
```

Now if you're looking for that as a more useful variable set:

```
key, value = h.find do |_, l|
  l.size == 1
end
# => [ 1, ["abc"]]
key
# => 1
value
# => ["abc"]
```

If you only care about the values, then it's even easier:

```
list = h.values.find do |l|
  l.size == 1
end
```

Comment: The `do ... end` syntax is a bit unusual here, given the assignment and the very short block content.

Comment: @Stefan It's the long form version of `{ ... }` which tends to make what's going on inside a lot more clear since it's exposed on its own line. That also makes adding comments easier.